# Change position dynamically angular.js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, position, styles

I have a question about dynamically changing position (bottom) in angular.js

I have a div with position fixed, and I must put it on the site depends on the height of header (which is above this div).

Header is changed dynamically (eg you click button "add" and it adds to your header 2 lines of text, so div has a higher height), so position of my div is related to this header. How can I do this?

Comment: ng-style or ng-class you can dynamically change css

Answer (score 0):

Put a div around your fixed position div that has `position: relative`.

Fixed position divs are taken out of the DOM flow and so do not take into account the position of other elements on the page. They can be positioned relative to their parent container however. So you create a parent container that wraps around your fixed div that can react to changes in the DOM, and the fixed div will then react to those changes.

```
<header></header>
<div class="container" style="position: relative">
    <div class="fixed-position-element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular.element(lite jquery), to manipulate of DOM elements.